# Encoding problem TCP communication between C# and Java

Tags: java, c#, android, encoding, tcp

I am just trying to send an `int` value from my Android app to my C# server, however I am messing something up since the values received on the server are impossible to convert to int due to encoding issues.

Android app is sending the `int` value (n):

```
OutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
int n = 1;
oos.write((""+n).getBytes());
oos.flush();
```

My TCP C# Server is reading:

```
byte[] message = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead=0;
bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
string dataReceived = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message);
```

> dataReceived is "??\0\u0005w\u00011\0\0.......0\0"

Answer (score 0):

No need to wrap the `OutputStream` in `ObjectOutputStream`.

Java Client:

```
OutputStream oos = socket.getOutputStream();
int n = 1;
oos.write((""+n).getBytes());
oos.flush();
```

C# Server:

```
byte[] message = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead=0;
while (true)
{
    bytesRead = 0;
    try
    {
        bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
    }
    catch
    {
        break;
    }

    if (bytesRead == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    //message has successfully been received
    ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
    string msg = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg.Replace("\r\n", "")))
    {
        int q = -1;
        if (int.TryParse(msg, out q))
        {
            queue.Enqueue(q);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using different encoding here. Java String.getBytes() default to unicode UTF-16, and can't be read by server side as ASCII.

So change to

```
oos.write((""+n).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```